# how to implement identity in .net core DbFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have an SQL Server DB that I reverse engineered into my .Net Core App. All is great....until now. I want to introduce Identity. There are plenty of examples on how to do this code first, but not DB First. Has anybody any ideas how I should go about this?

Comment: why don't you convert it to code first too?

Comment: The db is already there and it's quite large.

Comment: the size of the db doesn't matter.you can easily convert it to code first by using this : https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Comment: I've not used TT files since EF 4 and they were a pain. I'd like to steer away from them if possible. Also the static reference data files have a lot of data in them

Comment: You don't need to mess with T4 templates to reverse engineer the POCO classes and context, but that's not what you asked. Here is a technique for identity in db first: https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

Comment: @SteveGreene Thanks, this looks to be exactly what I need. I'll try it out and see where it gets' me.  I'd mark this as the answer, but you onkly made it a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the Link that @SteveGrenne offered, I did the following.

I created a .net core MVC project and set the project authentication to individual user. I then created a user as per the link. This created and generated the required tables into a default DB. I then scripted the tables and placed these into my live DB. From here on this is where my fix deviated from the suggestion. Using the `Scaffold-DbContext` command in the nuGet Package manager console I reverse engineered my DB into my desired project. in the Project.json files I then made a reference to the Identity and Cookies packages and changed my Repository Layers that were referencing `DbContext` to now reference `IdentityDbContext`